# How to create momentLocaleData.firstDayOfWeek() in luxon?

Tags: luxon

In moment you can call:

`momentLocaleData.firstDayOfWeek()`

Is it possible to get the same functionality in Luxon?

Comment: I fear that it is not possible since [docs](http://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/matrix.html#platform-caveats) states that: _Luxon doesn't have internationalized strings in its code; instead it relies on the hosts implementation of the Intl API_ and I always get monday as first day of the week (see `DateTime.local().setLocale('fr-CA').startOf('week').toISO()` vs `moment().locale('fr-ca').startOf('week').format()`) and there is no `week` parameter in [`startOf`](http://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-startOf) docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Luxon has added Localized week support in version `3.4.4`. Now you can use [`startOf`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof) using `useLocaleWeeks` option:

> `opts.useLocaleWeeks` `boolean` (default `false`)
>
> If true, use weeks based on the locale, i.e. use the locale-dependent start of the week

Example:

```js
// Luxon
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log( DateTime.local().setLocale('fr-CA').startOf('week', {useLocaleWeeks: true}).toISO() );
// Moment.js
console.log( moment().locale('fr-ca').startOf('week').format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Old answer for version before `3.4.4`:**

I fear that, at the moment (current version `2.4.0`), it is not possible achieve this using Luxon.

The Luxon 1.x [docs](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/1.28.0/docs/matrix.md#effects-of-missing-features) states:

> **Basic internationalization.** Luxon doesn't have internationalized strings in its code; instead it relies on the hosts implementation of the Intl API. This includes the very handy [toLocaleString](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocalestring). Most browsers and recent versions of Node support this.

while refence for version 2.x is in [Intl](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/intl) section

Moreover, using Luxon, you always get Monday as the first day of the week, as you can see in the following snippet:

```js
// Luxon
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log( DateTime.local().setLocale('fr-CA').startOf('week').toISO() );
// Moment.js
console.log( moment().locale('fr-ca').startOf('week').format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that, even if there is `'week'` parameter in [`startOf`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof) docs, it returns always Monday as first day of the week.

> "Set" this DateTime to the beginning of a unit of time.
>
> ```
> startOf(unit: string): DateTime
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `unit (string)` The unit to go to the beginning of. Can be 'year', 'quarter', 'month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', or 'millisecond'.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> DateTime.local(2014, 3, 3).startOf('week').toISODate(); //=> '2014-03-03', weeks always start on Mondays
> ```

Comment: Has been added in the meantime: *The unit to go to the beginning of. Can be 'year', 'quarter', 'month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', or 'millisecond'. - weeks always start on Mondays*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are right, _week_ has been added to [`startOf`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof) docs, but unfortunately the functionality asked in the question is still not available since it returns always Monday as first day of the week.