# It's there a way to get start of the week based on the locale with Luxon?

Tags: date, locale, luxon

It's there a way to get start of the week based on the locale with Luxon? I mean, I see it returns "Monday" for America, but also for France . I need to find a way to be Sunday for America and Monday for France, and so on based on locale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create momentLocaleData.firstDayOfWeek() in luxon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350110/how-to-create-momentlocaledata-firstdayofweek-in-luxon)

Comment: Hi @Elma, did you find a solution? I have same issue